# What is the best practice for setting up TFS for agile development?

Tags: tfs, agile, agile-project-management, team-project

I'm thinking of giving each part of the agile lifecycle its own project (TFS project, not csproj) as per Microsoft's agile template.

- Is it possible to move items (like User Stories or Tasks) from one Project to another?
- Does the organization of these projects have any bearing on or affect the actual software build (solutions, csproj, etc)?
- What is the recommended organizational structure of Projects, etc for an agile project?
- Are there any guides you can recommend for setting TFS up to work with the standard agile process?

Comment: There are some great tutorials out there. Just google them. To answer your question would probably exceed the text limit on SO.

Comment: Please check out https://www.plasticscm.com/

Answer (score 2):

Do not set up multiple TFS projects for the same team/product line. You can't move things from one to another and they won't be able to share a common parent source control so you would miss out on much of what source control has to offer. Do some research by reading the links on the other answers.

Answer (score -2):

I have never heard such a strange idea.

You should have one team project for each endeavor. Basically, a team project is the intersection of a team with a project.